# replacing escaped quotes in groovy

Tags: groovy, replaceall

I am unsure why this doesn't work:

```
  string.replaceAll('\\"','"')
```

I want to replace all  `\"` with `"`

Any idea?

I have also tried

```
 string.replaceAll("[\"]","\"")
```

Comment: Taking a guess, you would probably need `replaceAll("[\\\"]", "\"")` since the backslash before `"` just escapes it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck

Comment: What about `"\\\""`, `"[\\\\\"]"` or `"\\\\\""` for the first part? Either the `\"` sequence has to be represented with `\\"` internally in regex (it's the case in PHP) or the `[]` brackets are not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to the [`replaceAll` method](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern,%20java.lang.String)) is a regular expression, so the backslash character has significance there and needs to be escaped. You could use the forward-slash string delimiter to avoid double-escaping.

```
assert (/Hello, \"Joe\"/.replaceAll(/\\"/, '"') == 'Hello, "Joe"')
```